# yum update fails > Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: powerstack. Please verify its path and try again

Tags: centos6, yum

I'm trying to do **yum update** on my production server which is ended by throwing an error, this is what it returns for that command -

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.rit.edu
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirrors.rit.edu
 * updates: mirrors.rit.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
http://download.powerstack.org/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'download.powerstack.org'"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: powerstack. Please verify its path and try again
```

I've tried command **yum clean all** which returns this -

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Cleaning repos: base epel extras longview mod-pagespeed newrelic powerstack updates varnish-3.0 webtatic
Cleaning up Everything
```

This is my yum config (**/etc/yum.conf**)

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=16&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release

#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
multilib_policy=best
```

This is **/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo** config -

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

I can't install any package either, throws the same error. Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error shows that your machine couldn't connect to repository `powerstack`. To update your system, you could disable it in file `/etc/yum.repos.d/powerstack.repo` by changing `enable` from 1 to 0 or run `yum update --disablerepo=powerstack*"

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, this resolve this issue. I've another issue now - will post separately.